# Missing files when running unit tests locally

Tags: c#, unit-testing, jenkins, makefile, jenkins-pipeline

First of all please keep in mind that I am just discovering how "things" work in the DevOps world and my knowledge is pretty limited - especially in scripting (PS and C#).

So I have to figure it out how to set up some Javascript unit tests for an app - specifically to get the "Test Results Analyzer" widget up and running on the Jenkins website.

I am currently recycling code from another Jenkins pipeline (def) and using the already existing "run unit tests" stage in the makefile.include of the project which (from what the main Dev of the project told me) it never worked - was never tested - to try and make the tests run.

I thought the best way (without breaking anything on the main app) is to test locally via cygwin. 
I have mapped the project as a workspace in Perforce and tried to run the command from the makefile.include

```
$ make runRoutingPlannerCSTests
```

Which is working about half way and after it prompts me with some missing files errors which I was not able to find anywhere on my local project folder.

```
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'D:\src\project\ServicePlanning\BackendAPI\Comtec.Portal.OSPBackend.ApiModel\bin\Release\Comtec.Portnd [D:\src\project\ServicePlanning\Frontend_RoutingPlanner\Comtec.ServicePlanning.Frontend.RoutingPlanner.Tests\Comtec.ServicePlanning
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'D:\src\project\ServicePlanning\Frontend_RoutingPlanner\Comtec.ServicePlanning.Frontend.RoutingPlannngPlanner.dll' could not be found [D:\src\project\ServicePlanning\Frontend_RoutingPlanner\Comtec.ServicePlanning.Frontend.RoutingPlanntingPlanner.Tests.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'D:\src\project\ServicePlanning\Frontend_RoutingPlanner\Comtec.ServicePlanning.Frontend.RoutingPlannFrontend.RoutingPlanner.Model.dll' could not be found [D:\src\project\ServicePlanning\Frontend_RoutingPlanner\Comtec.ServicePlanning.Flanning.Frontend.RoutingPlanner.Tests.csproj]
Makefile.include:121: recipe for target `buildRoutingPlannerCSTests' failed
make: *** [buildRoutingPlannerCSTests] Error 1
```

and also

```
$ make runTests
```

Which gets stuck somewhere after running the Specrunner.html

```
######################################################
# run unit tests
######################################################
runTests: runRoutingPlannerJasmineTests runRoutingPlannerCSTests

runRoutingPlannerJasmineTests:
    $(RoutingPlanner_TESTS_UTILITIES_DIR)/bin/phantomjs.exe $(RoutingPlanner_TESTS_DIR)/Scripts/jasmine.js $(RoutingPlanner_TESTS_DIR)/jsTests/SpecRunner.html

buildRoutingPlannerCSTests:
    $(MSBUILD) `cygpath -a -w $(RoutingPlanner_TESTS_DIR)/Comtec.ServicePlanning.Frontend.RoutingPlanner.Tests.csproj` $(MSBUILD_OPTIONS) /t:Build /property:Configuration=$(VS_CONFIG) /fileloggerparameters:LogFile=`cygpath -a -w $(RoutingPlanner_TESTS_DIR)/Comtec.ServicePlanning.Tests-Build-$(VS_CONFIG).log`

runRoutingPlannerCSTests: buildRoutingPlannerCSTests
    @rm -f '$(shell cygpath -aw '$(RoutingPlanner_TESTS_DIR)/bin/$(VS_CONFIG)/Comtec.ServicePlanning.Frontend.RoutingPlanner.Tests.trx')'
    $(DOTNET_UNIT_MSTEST) /nologo '/testcontainer:$(shell cygpath -aw '$(RoutingPlanner_TESTS_DIR)/bin/$(VS_CONFIG)/Comtec.ServicePlanning.Frontend.RoutingPlanner.Tests.dll')'  '/resultsfile:$(shell cygpath -aw '$(RoutingPlanner_TESTS_DIR)/bin/$(VS_CONFIG)/Comtec.ServicePlanning.Frontend.RoutingPlanner.Tests.trx')'
```

This section has an additional section at the begging of the script where the paths have been added.

```
RoutingPlanner_FRONTEND_API_DIR ?= $(RoutingPlanner_FRONTEND_DIR)/Comtec.ServicePlanning.Frontend.RoutingPlanner
RoutingPlanner_TESTS_DIR = $(RoutingPlanner_FRONTEND_DIR)/Comtec.ServicePlanning.Frontend.RoutingPlanner.Tests
RoutingPlanner_TESTS_UTILITIES_DIR = $(RoutingPlanner_TESTS_DIR)/Utilities/phantomjs-2.0.0-windows
RoutingPlanner_UTILITIES_DIR = $(PREPARESETUPDIR)/RoutingPlannerPortalUtilities
```

To be honest I am not even sure if I am following the right path to this since the steps I have found on the internet are different from what I found in the project and what I believe should be done.

For example: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin

Mainly I believe this might be a simple "wrong path" issue but since my scripting skills are close to zero I am not sure what to modify and where.

I do not expect the solution at hand but I would really like to understand what the issues is or the proper way to actually make this work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using Windows or Linux to build? The `$` hints for Linux, which does not comprehend those Windows paths. A fully platform-independent build either requires that to be handled accordingly, or have specialized make files.

Comment: I'm working on a Windows machine and the app is hosted on Azure. To be honest I thought that the $ is actually for a PS variable or something but now that I think about it a make file has nothing to do with PS, right? It's C#?